# libgtk version mismatch in 19.04

Tags: apt, package-management, gtk, gtk3

I just upgraded from 18.10 to 19.04, and was immediately unable to get to my `gdm3` splash screen or to `gnome-shell`. With some trial and error on the `TTY` and a lot of googling I noticed that I get the following error when I try to run any gtk-based app:

```
$ gedit
gedit: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: pango_font_description_set_variations
```

I've tried purging and reinstalling `libgtk` (along with the dependent apps) a couple of times, but am still getting the same error. I've checked that I don't have any non-ubuntu sources in my `sources.list`, and when I install apps via `snap install` instead of `apt install` I don't get these errors. It's hard for me to believe that the wrong version of `libgtk` was packaged with this ubuntu version, especially as I don't see anyone else experiencing this problem, but I'm really not sure what to think.

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem could be or how I might go about fixing it? Traveling for work right now so I don't really have the materials to back up my home partition and do a full reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had some libraries in `/usr/local/lib/` that were not managed under any package, and which were shadowing the libraries where the "undefined" symbol was actually defined. Removing these libraries fixed the problem.

Thanks to [this post from way back when](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1323888) for pointing me in the right direction.

Beware the perils of manual library installation.